# Ajax multiple input not showing all data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck in multiple input. My code is not showing all data. below is the html I am using:

```
<form id="matkul" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Matakuliah</th>
                <th>Data Lain</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
<button id="post" type="submit">Save</button>
<button id="get">Get Data!</button>
```

below is the code to get the data

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#get").click(function() {
                var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Funisys.uii.ac.id%2Fuii-ras%2Fmatakuliah.asp%3Fidx%3D1%26session_id%3DxxbKiKJawuyrbaaiJ3Kabybabi3JJiKJrJyb3wiuKbbry0JbKiKbKr0yyrKK15933511%26no_mhs%3D%22&format=json';
                $.getJSON(url,
                    function(data) {
                        var id = data.query.results.body.table.tr.td.table.tr[2].td.table.tr;

                        for (var i = 1; i <= id.length; i++) {
                            $("<tr> <td> <input name='fmatakuliah' value='"+id[i].td[1].a.content+"'> </td> <td> <input name='fdata' value='" + id[i].td[1].a['href'] + "'> </td> </tr>").appendTo("#matkul tbody");
                        };
                    });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

from the above code output will be

```
Matakuliah      Data Lain
StringOne       OtherData
StringTwo       OtherData
```

below is the ajax post code, but when it is already sending the data, the alert does not show all the data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post").click(function(){
        string = $("form").serialize();
        alert(string); // this alert is normal, show all data
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/save.php",
            data: string,
            success: function(data){
                alert("Success!"+data); //this not normal, not show all data
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

below is the code on save.php

```
print_r($_GET);
```

The latest response is showing like this

```
Array
(
    [fmatakuliah] => Wide Area Network
    [fdata] => matakuliahdetail.asp?session_id=xxbKiKJawuyrbaaiJ3Kabybabi3JJiKJrJyb3wiuKbbry0JbKiKbKr0yyrKK15933511&mk=52323605&kur=2010
)
```

My question is how to show all data and save it to the database?

Comment: on this line alert("Success!"+data); data is something returned by your save.php page. Line string = $("form").serialize(); is where you serialize all of your input in the form to make it as string to be used in save.php. Please share us your save.php contents.

Comment: What does save.php look like. what code outputs the data from save.php. all you ahve is `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: try `echo json_encode($_GET);` and then `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }` then check the console log

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to change the AJAX type from GET to POST:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/save.php",
        data: string,
        success: function(data){
            alert("Success!"+data); //this not normal, not show all data
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I know for sure that using a GET when you are saving to a db isn't the right way to go.  Also, I don't know much php, just javascript...so I can't help you much there.